# UUID and JPA2.0

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

We have a postgres database that suffers from indexes being slow on strings formatted as UUID:s. Slow compared to using UUID as datatype in the tables.

We would like to fix this and convert the strings to database native uuid but we are stuck with Jboss EAP6.4, eg JPA2.0, and to make things worse we have a bunch of database-tests against HSQLDB (to avoid setup of central databases for unit testing).

I have tried to google around but most solutions seems to fall back on non uuid type in the database (strings or binaries) or is about JPA2.2, not to mention that they are, well, old.

So, basically, is this a problem that can be solved within a reasonable effort or should I go back to ops and say what we need to upgrade Jboss to resent version of Jboss and Hibernate where this supposably isn't a problem? Is it a solved problem now?

Comment: one question, when you say "your indexes being slow", you mean, slow  creating index when new object is added? or slow when you read from database? or you can you explain better?

Comment: @duardito Using uuid as the id instead of a string in a uuid-format in the database,  will perform better when searching a table for the id of that table. So slow might not be the right word since it is relative to the potential performance we could have.